# jQuery .click(function() not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox, iframe

I am trying to load in a YouTube iFrame when a user clicks on a holding image using jQuery. This works fine in all browsers apart from Firefox.

Any idea what may be causing the issue?

For the live example visit http://roelto.com/ and click on the main image. You will see the iframe load fine in Chrome, Safari, IE but not in Firefox

This is the jQuery I'm using...

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#dna_video_thumbnail').click(function() {
      jQuery('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uIYa7RiDjs8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#dna_video');
      jQuery(this).remove();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using newest jQuery?  Coz when i opened console it showed that can't get height of some element, which crashes JS from doing in FF.

Comment: have you try like as $(document).on('click','yourelement',function(){ // to do}); ?

Comment: Nevermind, you have the script on-page. Nevertheless, still have an error in dna_Scripts.js@125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function getHeight(); on line 125 of dna_script.js. It is undefined. You can see that in Firefox's console.

Move the function declaration above the function call.

Comment: Yep - you got it - I should have spotted that lol - thank you ever so much

Answer (score 1):

Using this:

```
 $(document).on('click','yourelement',function(){ 
$('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uIYa7RiDjs8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#dna_video');
      $(this).remove();
});
```